# How to manually assign user passwords via PHP file

Tags: php

I am a new user and I have a simple question. How do I set a password for a user to log in to my site with PHP? I have no MySQL database just a iOS code/host app. I know this isn’t the most secure option, but only me and my friends are on the site so it doesnt matter. I tried the following:

```
$password = [
           'john'   => 'password1',
           'paul'   => 'password2',
           'george' => 'password3',
           'robert'  => 'password4'
        ];
        
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $pass = $password[ $_POST['username'] ];
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $pass)) {
        echo "Log in successful<br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "Invalid log in<br>";
    }
}
```

This is my HTML login form code for reference:

```
<body>    
    <center> <h1>Login</h1> </center>   
    <form>
        <div class="container">   
            <label>Username:</label>   
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="" required>  
            <label>Password:</label>   
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="" required>  
            <button type="submit">Login</button>   
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me   
            <button type="button" class="cancelbtn"> Cancel</button>   
            <a href="">Forgot password?</a>
        </div>   
    </form>
</body>     
</html>
```

But it didn’t work… So any help is appreciated.

Comment: Whats there in` password_verify` function ?

Comment: `input` should have a valid `name="username" `

Comment: The `name` attribute specifies the name of an `<input>` element.

The `name` attribute is used to reference elements in a JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted.

__Note: Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed` when submitting a form.`__

Comment: As per above comment, write a quick test method to log any input to console. Run it against the form and find out whether or not the data is submitting. Or you can hardcode a dummy input, instead of pulling the form data. Each option will narrow the scope of your issue to either the front end or back end.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are in best of health. There are lots of issues in your code. I am adding some points.

1. You did not set username and password as names in your input fields.
2. You are using POST method in your PHP code but on HTML your form's method attribute is missing.
3. Most important, the way you are adding the condition of **password_verify** is incorrect.

You can use the below code. I have tested it.

```
<?php
$password = [
    'john'   => 'password1',
    'paul'   => 'password2',
    'george' => 'password3',
    'robert'  => 'password4'
];
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $pass = @$password [ $_POST['username'] ];
    if (!isset($pass))
    {
        echo "Invalid log in<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        if ($_POST['password'] == $pass)
        {
            echo "Log in successful<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Invalid log in<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>

<body>    
    <center> <h1>Login</h1> </center>   
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="container">   
            <label>Username:</label>   
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>  
            <label>Password:</label>   
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>  
            <button type="submit">Login</button>   
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me   
            <button type="button" class="cancelbtn"> Cancel</button>   
            <a href="">Forgot password?</a>
        </div>   
    </form>
</body>     
</html>
```

Comment: Also, the name of this file should be with .php extension and this code can run only using some local server if you are using it on your system.

Comment: I am new to PHP if that is what you mean ;) The php is appearing on my screen… why is that?

Comment: This is because you are directly running the file in your browser. PHP Coding need a server to run.

Comment: There are many tutorials or documentations available describing how to run PHP on your system. You can check them.

Comment: On IOS? Do you have a link to one?

Comment: You can try this link [https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-run-a-php-file-in-xampp]

Comment: For IOS you have to purpose some hosting and website and give the URL of API to it so it can run.